# Limit to number of AND statements in Where clause?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have 4 text boxes on a userform in Excel.  Each texbox corresponds to a field in a table in Access.  I would like to search for records that match criteria specified in each text box.   I’ve constructed a SQL statement using AND to include three of the text boxes.  However, when I add a fourth text box I get an error message.  Is there a limit to how many AND statement I could include?  How do I fix this issue?

Thank you for your help in advance!

```
SQLwhere = "WHERE "
If Len(var & vbNullString) <> 0 Then
    If CheckBox1 = True Then
    SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[Table1].[RunDate] = '" & var & "' AND "
    Else
    SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[Table1].[RunDate] LIKE '" & var & "%" & "' AND "
    End If
End If
If Len(var2 & vbNullString) <> 0 Then
    If CheckBox1 = True Then
    SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[Table1].[SampleID] = '" & var & "' AND "
    Else
    SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[Table1].[SampleID] LIKE '" & var2 & "%" & "' AND "
    End If
End If
If Len(var3 & vbNullString) <> 0 Then
    If CheckBox1 = True Then
    SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[Table1].[Tube] = '" & var3 & "' AND "
    Else
    SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[Table1].[Tube] LIKE '" & var3 & "%" & "' AND "
    End If
End If
If Len(var4 & vbNullString) <> 0 Then
    If CheckBox1 = True Then
    SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[Table1].[Test] = '" & var4 & "' AND "
    Else
    SQLwhere = SQLwhere & "[Table1].[Test] LIKE '" & var4 & "%" & "' AND "
    End If
End If


StrSql = "SELECT * FROM [Table1] "

 'Remove the last AND applicable

If SQLwhere = "WHERE " Then
    SQLwhere = ""
Else
    SQLwhere = Left(SQLwhere, Len(SQLwhere) - 6)
End If

StrSql = StrSql & SQLwhere
```

Comment: There is a limit, some google results say its 40 conditions.

Comment: @BGeorge The OP states that the user form is in Excel and connects to Access.  So this code is in Excel, the tag is correct and your edit should be removed.

Comment: What's the error? On which line? What's the value of `StrSql` before you try to run it?

Comment: *I get an error message*. It would be very helpful if you shared that error message with us as well. It's information you already have right in front of you that's extremely relevant - why would you not provide that to us too?

Answer (score 0):

**An error message would really help!**

I see that you are subtracting `6` from SQLwhere which would eliminate the last apostrophe ' encapsulation; try changing it to `-5`.

Also, if there is a value containing an apostrophe `'` in any of the text boxes then your SQL will not work.